# Дата выхода json api 1.2

Tags: json

Уточните, пожалуйста, дату выхода json api 1.2, в которой добавлена возможность создания идентичных веб-хуков на разные url.
При использовании двух связанных Retail CRM систем (одну для продаж, другую для сервиса) вторую (по обработке сервисных обращений) можно будет итегрировать с Мой Склад, с которым уже интегрирована основная Retail CRM-система (по продажам)?
Мой склад версии 1.0 не позволяет создавать 2 веб-хука для одной системы Мой склад? Но готовится обновление 2.0, в котором, вероятно, такая возможность появится?

Comment: При использовании двух связанных Retail CRM систем (одну для продаж, другую для сервиса) вторую (по обработке сервисных обращений) можно будет итегрировать с Мой Склад, с которым уже интегрирована основная Retail CRM-система (по продажам)?

Comment: Мой склад версии 1.0 не позволяет создавать 2 веб-хука для одной системы Мой склад? Но готовится обновление 2.0, в котором, вероятно, такая возможность появится?

Comment: Какой вообще отношение имеет retail crm к json api 1.2?

Comment: Используем Retail CRM, интегрированную с Мой Склад. Хотим подключить вторую Retail CRM и интегрировать с тем же Мой Склад.  Сейчас, если я верно осведомлён, это невозможно. Но во второй версии такая возможность появится, если я правильно понимаю. Почему и спрашиваю дату выхода обновления. Если я в чем-то не прав - прошу меня поправить.

Comment: Дмитрий, ну так при чём тут дата выхода json api-то? Почему в тегах один только json?

Comment: Я не тех.специалист, пользуюсь этим сайтом впервые. Буду рад любой помощи в решении задачи.

Comment: Для того, чтобы задача решилась, вам надо её сформулировать понятно для остальных (это не единственное условие, но основное). Сейчас вопрос выглядит примерно так: *"в огороде Retail CRM, когда выйдет JSON-API в киеве?"* На вторую часть вопроса вам уже ответили, но лично меня смущает первая.

Comment: Складывается ощущение, что вы либо считаете JSON-API частью Retail CRM, либо спрашиваете вообще не про JSON-API...

Comment: Вопрос в том, можно ли интегрировать две Retail CRM с одним и тем же Мой Склад? Как это сделать? Есть ли нюансы? Также стоит принять во внимание, что с Retail CRM интегрирован СДЭК, который есть желание использовать и для второй Reyail CRM системой, которую планируется использовать для отработки обращений по сервису, а не для продаж.

Comment: А при чём тут json api?

Comment: Мне про него сказали в тех.поддержке Мой Склал

Comment: Так, может быть, вам надо там и про дату выхода спрашивать?

Comment: Там не могут ответить на этот вопрос и адресовали меня сюда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Планируемый срок выхода [JSON-API 1.2](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/milestone/3) под конец мая, точной даты пока нигде не было написано.